# go cannot use output (type string) as type io.Writer in argument to template Execute

Tags: go

It's easy to execute template ('tmplhtml' in my case) in 'go' to *os.Stdout* but how to write it to a string 'output' so I can later i.e. send html in mail using `"gopkg.in/gomail.v2"` ?

```
var output string
    t := template.Must(template.New("html table").Parse(tmplhtml))
    err = t.Execute(output, Files)
m.SetBody("text/html", output) //"gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
```

Build error reads **'cannot use output (type string) as type io.Writer in argument to t.Execute: string does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)'** I can implement Writer method but it is supposed to return integer **Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write to a buffer as follows as this implements the interface `io.Writer`.  Its basically missing a Write method, which you could build your own, but a buffer is more straight forward:

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
t := template.Must(template.New("html table").Parse(tmplhtml))
err = t.Execute(buf, Files)
```

Comment: cannot use buf (type *bytes.Buffer) as type string in argument to m.SetBody

Comment: a buffer is easily converted to a string,  I think its just `buf.String()` the docs are https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.String

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [strings.Builder](//pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder):

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "text/template"
)

func main() {
   t, err := new(template.Template).Parse("hello {{.}}")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b := new(strings.Builder)
   t.Execute(b, "world")
   println(b.String())
}
```